# unable to select date via calendar in selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I am learning selenium and stuck on date pickup via calendar, cannot find any id or name to use to identify the calendar and select a date.
Here is the HTML code
[image: code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), please make your question Minimal, Complete, Verifiable [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which have to can be reproduced to help you.

Comment: Also please post the code as text, not as an image, so people can copy&paste it into their own editors and so the code can be found by search engines